# Find shortest path in a weighted digraph with GraphFrames Spark

Tags: shortest-path, graphframes, weighted-graph

The graphFrames package of spark is great. I can find the shortest path from "a" to "d" with the command

```
val results = g.shortestPaths.landmarks(Seq("a", "d")).run()
```

but what how can I define a weighted graph and compute shortest path between two nodes?

Thanks.